# How can I not put data in ImageField in Django?

Tags: python, django, imagefield

I am to store images in imagefield. But I don't want to print out an error even if I don't put an image in ImageField. In other words, I want to leave ImageField null.I also tried null=True and blank=True to do this, but it didn't work properly. What should I do to make it possible? Here is my code.

```
class post (models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    image1 = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    image4 = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    image5 = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: did you migrate your changes, also example where this fails to you would be beneficiary

Comment: @iklinac yes I already migrate it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly use an `ImageField()` you need to install Pillow with `pip install Pillow`

It would be better to make an Image model and reference it with a ForeignKey from your Post model like this:

```py
from django.db import models


class Image (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'image'


class Post (models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'post'
```

Django will try and upload an image to the Media root, so add the `MEDIA_URL` to the bottom of your `settings.py` like this:

```
# settings.py 

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Dont forget to clear your database and redo your migrations and you should be able to keep the ImageField empty if you want